# Resources, "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly (Image.Save), and TIFFs?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, tiff, resourcebundle

VS2008 SP1

The C# compiler is giving me ["Generate" task failed unexpectedly ... (Image.Save)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586646/the-generateresource-task-failed-unexpectedly) when I try to compile my project, which has a resx file to which I've added a TIFF file.

I haven't yet written any code to reference the resource -- just having the TIFF file included in the resource causes the compile failure.

How can I compile this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem with VS2008 SP1 Pro Edition (9.0.30729.1 SP) when I tried to add TIFF files to my Resource.

Renaming the "TIFF" file to use a .dat extension (anything non-.tif is the point, I think) before adding it to the Resource solved the problem for me.